# Change time format in laravel

Tags: laravel, datetime

I am very new to laravel and I have an input for date of birth whose format is DD-MM-YYYY, but I have a SQL Error because the default format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, how can I change this default format?. This is my migration code for the specific date.

```
$table->date('date_of_birth');
```

Comment: Change the input format before the insert. You can use Carbon to do it `Carbon::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", "05-07-2020")->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$table->dateTime('date_of_birth');
```

Or,

```
$table->timestamp('date_of_birth');
```

`timestamp` and `dateTime` store a date `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)` together in a single field i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

The difference between the two is that `timestamp` can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as it's value, whenever the database record is updated.

Their major difference is the range. For `DateTime` its up to year `9999` while for `timestamp` its only up to year `2038`. Other differences include the amount of bytes needed to store each.